# RouteCollection.MapRoute not appearing when passing into a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

**RouteConfig**:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Bootstrap routes

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Field routes

            FieldRoutes fieldRoutes = new FieldRoutes();

            fieldRoutes.DefineCreate( ref routes );
            fieldRoutes.DefineDetails( ref routes );
            fieldRoutes.DefineEdit( ref routes );
            fieldRoutes.DefineDelete( ref routes );

        // ...
```

**ICRUDRoutes interface**:

```
public interface ICRUDRoutes
{
    void DefineCreate( ref RouteCollection routes );
    void DefineDetails( ref RouteCollection routes );
    void DefineList( ref RouteCollection routes );
    void DefineEdit( ref RouteCollection routes );
    void DefineDelete( ref RouteCollection routes );
}
```

**FieldRoute class**

```
public class FieldRoutes : ICRUDRoutes
{
    public void DefineCreate( ref RouteCollection routes )
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Soft delete a field",
            url: "field/delete/{fieldID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Field", action = "Delete" },
            constraints: new { id = RoutingConstraints.ID }
        );
        // routes.MapRoute does not exist as a function, but it exists in the RouteConfig, how does this work?
    }

    // ...
```

The `routes.MapRoute` does not exist as a function after passing the `Routecollection` through as a ref or otherwise, but it exists in the `RouteConfig`, how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the namespace:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

This is because `MapRoute` is an extension method. In order for it to appear on the object, you need to import the namespace the extension method is in.

Comment: The reason for this is that `MapRoute` is an extension method. In order for it to appear on the object, you need to import the namespace the extension method is in.